# Как я могу обновить 1 строчку в Firebase?

Tags: kotlin, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как изменить через код чтобы менялся только exp? я пытался сделать так

```
 val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/$uid")
 reference.setValue(extraExp)
```

Но в итоге в записи стиралось все кроме **exp**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getReference("users/$uid/exp")
```

И устанавливать value типа int

Comment: спасибо догадался, но думаю другим поможет)